# Master detail interface with multiple detail table views like Mail.app

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsarraycontroller, nsoutlineview, master-detail

I have a Cocoa app with a similar layout like Mail.app:

- A source list on the left where the user can select one of multiple entries
- A detail table view in the main content area showing a list based on the selected item on the left

I'd like the selection in the detail table view to be maintained separately for each master item.

Currently I have only *one detail table view and one array controller*. When the master selection changes, I update the `contents` binding for the detail array controller.

I think I may need multiple detail array controllers -- one for each entry in the master list.

Is there an easier way/recommended pattern to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an array controller for each table. For each detail array controller, you need to bind the `contents` binding to the `selectedObjects` key of the master array controller.

So if you had three array controllers, `master`, `detail1` and `detail2`, then the `content` binding of `detail1` should be set to `master` using a key path of `selectedObjects`.

The `content` binding of `detail2` should be set to `detail1`, also using a key path of `selectedObjects`.

You don't need to change the `contents` binding programmatically.

Comment: Would this mean that I also need a separate table for each entry in the master list? I'd like to avoid that. Also, why would I need to bind `detail2` to `detail1`?